# Oracle ADF table scrolls automatically

Tags: javascript, html-table, oracle-adf, vertical-scrolling

I have an Oracle ADF table which is scrollable and has multiple rows. Sometimes when scrolled to some rows, it will start scrolling up automatically and slowly, even after mouse is released.
Can it be prevented using JavaScript?
P.S : jQuery is not used in the application.

Comment: It looks like a framework bug, maybe you are using an old ADF version ?

Comment: Is it possible to include more information about the environment and versions you are using? Also a minimal reproducible example may help get a workable answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Can you try in new application.
Most cases this is related to any CSS effect. Try commenting out any CSS applied on the table both custom and generic

Comment: Can you provide an example of this problem as you have described? It's hard to understand what you mean without an example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example